# Create and edit object using modal in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've been trying to create and edit an object using a modal view in the index html in Rails. I'm using twitter bootstrap in the project. I m so far successful in creating the object using the modal. 
For things to work, I had to create an object called @post = Post.new in my index action.

Since before the edit modal is displayed, the edit object must be ready as @post = Post.find(params[:id]), but it happens in the edit action.

Is their a way using which I can initialize @post for my edit modal view before it is displayed?

Here's my code:

index.html.erb

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Posts</h1>
</div>


<% @posts do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.name %></td>
    <td><%= post.description %></td>

    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post), :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-min-standard-width',  :data => {:toggle => "modal", :target => "#editItemModal"} , :remote => true %>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', post, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete, :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger btn-min-standard-width'  %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>


<%= link_to 'New Item', new_post_path, 
        :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-standard-width' ,  :data => {:toggle => "modal", :target => "#newItemModal"} , :remote => true %>





<div id="newItemModal" class="modal hide fade" >
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button></h1>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>New item </h1>
    </div>

    <%= render :partial => 'form' %>
</div>


<div id="editItemModal" class="modal hide fade" >
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button></h1>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Edit item </h1>
    </div>

    <%= render :partial => 'form' %>
 </div>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%if @post%>

    <%= form_for(@post, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', :remote => true } ) do |f| %>


     <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
        <div class="controls">
           <%= f.text_field :name %>
       </div>
     </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
        <div class="controls">
            <%= f.text_area :description %>
        </div>
     </div>


    <div class="form-actions">
       <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
     </div>


    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

PostController

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

 def index
    @post = Post.new
    @posts = Post.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end

 def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
       format.html # show.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @post }
     end
  end

 def new
    @post = Post.new
 end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
     format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end
```

............

Comment: You can get more helpful answers by posting bits of code

Comment: Updated question with code snippets

Comment: @random did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

As long as I understand you want to use instance variable @post in the edit modal view.

Without knowing your code base, what can I say:

1. Find the corresponding action in the controller that renders the edit modal view, create one if there is no
2. Initialize @post with the model Post found by id, just simply copy and paste that into the proper action
3. Call it within the view scope

Hope that answers your question

Comment: Since modal is displayed within the index html, I think @post should be defined within the index action. But when I click the new or edit button, the corresponding actions are called.

Comment: Render `<%= render :partial => 'form' %>` in your index view, where you would like to see your form for object creation.

Comment: It didn't help. any other suggestions?